# Issue in property binding in Angular through array

Tags: angular

I wanted to render three cards with given contents in array using string interpollation. As well as set the style property of the specific card according to the given string in the array.

But I am having issue setting style property to my card. Issue is whenever I try to set style using string interpolation my view just displays blank.

```
 <div class="row-sm-2" *ngFor="let post of classifications">
     <mat-card style={{ post.margin }}>
         <p style="color: #62697D;">{{ post.content }}</p>
     </mat-card>
 </div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  classifications = [
    {margin: '0px; width: 100%', content: 'Hello there'},
    {margin: '20px; width: 100%', content: 'Hi there'},
    {margin: '20px; width: 100%', content: 'Well its angular'}
  ];

}
```

Comment: missing quotes? `<mat-card style="{{ post.margin }}">` Also check the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either enclose it in quotations, or bind to `[style]`. Also it'd be better to structure the data the following way and access the styles using `post.style` instead of `post.margin`.

```
classifications = [
  {style: 'margin: 0px, width: 100%', content: 'Hello there'},
  {style: 'margin: 20px, width: 100%', content: 'Hi there'},
  {style: 'margin: 20px, width: 100%', content: 'Well its angular'}
];
```

```html
<div class="row-sm-2" *ngFor="let post of classifications">
  <mat-card style="{{ post.style }}">
    <p style="color: #62697D;">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Or

```html
<div class="row-sm-2" *ngFor="let post of classifications">
  <mat-card [style]="post.style">
    <p style="color: #62697D;">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Well first solution doesn't works. And your second solution is pretty much close to the answer. Instead of [ngStyle] I only used [style] and it worked.

Comment: Yeah I've edited the answer. `[ngStyle]` expects an object as input. But you might have to modify the actual string that denotes the style. `'0px; width: 100%'` isn't a valid style.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are missing quotes, `<mat-card style="{{ post.margin }}">`

Secondly, this will resolve to a rubish markup like

`<mat-card style="0px; width: 100%">` which is invalid - 0px of what?

use `ngStyle` to set element style dynamically.

Comment: Yeh I did saw that mistake and corrected it. But ngStyle is not working in my case. Instead I just only used [style]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row-sm-2" *ngFor="let post of classifications">
    <mat-card [style]= 'post.margin'>
        <p style="color: #62697D;">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

The issue was I was doing string interpolation instead I wanted to do is property binding all I have to do was remove curly braces